# Generate an OpenAPI NestJs server stub

Tags: nestjs, mustache, openapi-generator

I'm messing around with custom templates for the OpenAPI-Generator CLI to make a server stub for NestJs (controllers, services, mongoose model templates) and I can't seem to strip off the *Service for the classname mustache template.

For example:

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Patch } from '@nestjs/common';
/**
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string {
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}
*/

{{#operations}}
{{#description}}
    /**
    * {{&description}}
    */
{{/description}}
@Controller('{{classname}}')
export class {{classname}}Controller {
{{#operation}}
    /**
    * {{summary}}
    * {{notes}}
    {{#allParams}}* @param {{paramName}} {{description}}
    {{/allParams}}*/
    {{nickname}}({{#allParams}}{{paramName}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}: {{{dataType}}}, {{/allParams}}): {{#returnType}}{{{returnType}}}{{/returnType}}{{^returnType}}{}{{/returnType}};
{{/operation}}
}
{{/operations}}
```

I do like there is a nodejs-express template, but it isn't either typescript nor a framework like NestJs.  As in it is a good starter, but not an end-goal for me.

Has anyone had any success or seen the templates for making a server stub and not an Axios client library.

Comment: Please open an issue via http://github.com/openAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new and we (the community) will help you there.